# CakePHP Custom Stateless Authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm writing my own stateless authentication class for CakePHP. I believe I've got the class written correctly, when I manually trigger the `$this->Auth->identify()` method it will correctly log me in.

I am having trouble so that it logs me in on every page...you know, stateless...

In my `AppController::initialize` I have the following

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth');
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', ['CustomAuthenticate']);
$this->Auth->config('checkAuthIn', ['Controller.initialize']);
```

The `AppController::beforeRender` has

```
$auth_user = TableRegistry::get('Users')->getFullUser( $this-> Auth->user('id') );
```

I thought the part with `checkAuthIn` was going to be the magic line that made it all worked, but I guess it wasn't (unless there is still something else I need to do).

I am currently getting `Fatal Error(1): Call to a memeber function user() on a non-object in [.../src/Controller/AppController.php, line 78]`

#### Links

- [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160672/cakephp-auth-getuser-in-beforefilter)
- [Some documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#deciding-when-to-run-authentication)

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in your `CustomAuthenticate` class.

Comment: @ndm My Authentication class extends directly from the `EventListenerInterface` (as opposed to Base/Basic/Digest Authentication). I believe I've implemented all the same functions that are in both Base and Basic Authentication

Right now, the `$this->Auth->user('id')` is erroring out in the `beforeRender` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I changed this

```
$this->Auth->config('checkAuthIn', ['Controller.initialize']);
```

to this

```
$this->Auth->config('checkAuthIn', 'Controller.initialize');
```

(took it out of the array)