# Is it required to use sessions while writing API in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Connect + ExpressJs.

I'm confused about the point of sessions and session management while writing RESTfull API. Can anyone explain to me the point of session management here?

Edit:

Was going through this example on ExpressJs which does indulge in sessions:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js

And thus was confused about the usage of sessions if I'm doing an Oauth2.0 API.

Comment: Could you provide some specific code that you're referencing?  It's hard to know what you're trying to do without any background whatsoever

Comment: I'm writing an API that is authenticated by Oauth2.0, an api that will be used by mobile apps. I do intend to write a web app, too. I was confused about the usage of sessions as I was already using an authenticating mechanism.

Comment: So if you look at that example, it's not actually using the session for the API.  It's used to login the user and to display flash messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't **need** session management when you're writing a RESTful API unless you plan on doing something that would need to authenticate the user across multiple requests.  For example, maybe you want a user with a cookie to not need to use an API token or you want to cut back on database requests by using cookies.

Most REST services just look up a user using some kind of API key or token though, so no sessions are necessary.

These questions might be helpful:

- [Do sessions really violate RESTfulness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness)
- [Is it good to implement REST api using Sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711044/is-it-good-to-implement-rest-api-using-sessions)

Comment: Yes, in fact that was where I was confused as to point of sessions if most transactions will be API based. Though, I presume, I've to do session management once it becomes a web app.

Comment: A better example of when it might be good to use sessions might be for a client side javascript app.  You don't want to store the API key on the client, so you authenticate with a cookie and they can consume that API without it.